# Apache Ignite .Net 2.8.1: Affinity collocation with QueryEntity

Tags: ignite

I'm using Apache Ignite v.2.8.1 .Net on a Windows 10 machine.

I am trying to use affinity collocation on a query-enabled cache. The entities I store in cache have a primary key named "Id" and an affinity key named "PartnerId". Both keys are of the type Int32. I'm defining the cache as follows:

```
new CacheConfiguration("BespokeCharge")
        {
            KeyConfiguration = new[]
            {
                    new CacheKeyConfiguration()
                    {
                        AffinityKeyFieldName = "PartnerId",
                        TypeName = typeof(BespokeCharge).Name
                    }
            }
        };
```

Next I use the following code to add the data:

```
var cache = Ignite.GetCache<AffinityKey, BespokeCharge>("BespokeCharge")
cache.Put(new AffinityKey(entity.Id, entity.PartnerId), entity)
```

So far so good. Since I want to be able to use SQL to search for bespoke charges, I also add a QueryEntity configuration:

```
new CacheConfiguration("BespokeCharge",
            new QueryEntity(typeof(AffinityKey), typeof(BespokeCharge))
            {
                KeyFieldName = "Id",
                TableName = "BespokeCharge"
            })
        {
            KeyConfiguration = new[]
            {
                    new CacheKeyConfiguration()
                    {
                        AffinityKeyFieldName = "PartnerId",
                        TypeName = typeof(BespokeCharge).Name
                    }
            }
        };
```

When I run the code, both Ignite and my app crash and the following error is logged:

> JVM will be halted immediately due to the failure: [failureCtx=FailureContext [type=CRITICAL_ERROR, err=class o.a.i.i.processors.cache.persistence.tree.CorruptedTreeException: B+Tree is corrupted [pages(groupId, pageId)=[IgniteBiTuple [val1=1565129718, val2=844420635164729]], cacheId=-1278247946, cacheName=BESPOKECHARGES, indexName=BESPOKECHARGES_ID_ASC_IDX, msg=Runtime failure on row: Row@29db2fbe[ key: AffinityKey [idHash=8137191, hash=783909474, key=3, affKey=2], val: UtilityClick.BillValidation.Shared.InMemory.Model.BespokeCharge [idHash=889383506, hash=-399638125, BespokeChargeTypeId=4, ChargeValue=100.0000, ChargeValueIncCommission=100.0000, Id=3, PartnerId=2, QuoteRecordId=5] ][ 4, 100.0000, 100.0000, , 2, 5 ]]]]

When I tried to define QueryEntity with the key type of int instead of AffinityKey, I got a different error with the same outcome -- a crash.

> JVM will be halted immediately due to the failure: [failureCtx=FailureContext [type=CRITICAL_ERROR, err=java.lang.ClassCastException: class o.a.i.cache.affinity.AffinityKey cannot be cast to class java.lang.Integer (o.a.i.cache.affinity.AffinityKey is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; java.lang.Integer is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')]]

What am I doing wrong? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Can you try `typeof(T).FullName` instead of `typeof(T).Name`?

Comment: @PavelTupitsyn Thank you, will do. The "T" is BespokeCharge (sorry, I forgot to replace T with a real entity type for clarify)

Comment: Let me know how it goes. And it would be great to have a reproducer - there is certainly some bug in Ignite - it should not crash JVM just because of a misconfiguration.

Comment: @PavelTupitsyn I've got the same error as above "B+Tree is corrupted".

Comment: @PavelTupitsyn I'll try to create a reproducer project.

Comment: @PavelTupitsyn done: https://github.com/alexavrutin/IgniteQueryEntityAffinityRepro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`KeyFieldName = "Id"` setting is the problem. It sets `Id` field to be used as a cache key, which is `int`, but then we use `AffinityKey` as a cache key, which causes a type mismatch.

In this case I don't think we need `KeyFieldName` at all, removing it fixes the problem, and `SELECT` queries should not be affected by this change.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try. How will the SQL engine know that the Id field is the key field if I don't specify it explicitly? Is there some kind of convention to consider all fields with the name "Id" key fields like in EF?

Comment: Thank you again, this solves the issue. But another question arises: what is the correct way to construct a LINQ/SQL query to search by key and affinity key? Is it a correct LINQ query?

                IQueryable<ICacheEntry<AffinityKey, BespokeCharge>> query = cache.AsCacheQueryable();

                var result = query
                    .Where(m => m.Value.Id == 1 && m.Value.PartnerId == 1)
                    .FirstOrDefault()
                    ?.Value;

Comment: @AlexAvrutin just use the key as is: `cache.Query(new SqlFieldsQuery("select * from BespokeCharge where _key=?", new AffinityKey(id, partnerId)))` or with LINQ `var key = new AffinityKey(bespokeCharge.Id, bespokeCharge.PartnerId); var qry = cache.AsCacheQueryable().Where(p => p.Key == key);`

Comment: Note that it is more efficient to do `cache.Get(key)` instead of an SQL query

Comment: I guess I still need to specify the affinity key in the SQL queries if I want the query to run on the right partition, not on all partitions?

Comment: @AlexAvrutin If the cache key is present in the `where` clause like above, Ignite will figure it out for you. Or do you mean something else?

Comment: I wonder if I can specify only the affinity key, without the primary key? For example, I have a query where I specify some other fields in the predicate + affinity key to assign a partition to run the query on. 99% of my queries will be single-partition queries.

Comment: Sorry, another question. Do I need an Id column in the entity at all if I have to use _key in queries anyway?

Comment: You can get rid of `Id` and `PartnerId` in the entity since they are present in the key anyway, but you'll have to use a custom key class instead of predefined `AffinityKey` in this case, so that `Id` and `PartnerId` are marked with `[QuerySqlField]` and are available in SQL.